# Hazelcast server with persistence

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Can I know Hazelcast support disk persistence? In other words can I use Hazelcast as regular database? (Like apache ignite).

Answer (score 2):

No, Hazelcast is an in-memory data store. It does not support persistence.

One corner case that is supported in Hazelcast is, so-called, Hot Restart, but it's limited to the scenarios when you need to shut down your cluster for maintenance or your cluster suddenly crashes. You can read more at [Hazelcast: Hot Restart](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/storage/hot-restart-persistence.html).

Comment: I will add a note that we have it on our roadmap to extend the Hot Restart feature to full mirrored persistence this year (disclaimer: I work at Hazelcast)

Comment: In addition to the above, Hazelcast does provide SPI for you to implement your own persistence for various data structures, e.g. IMap (https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/data-structures/map.html#loading-and-storing-persistent-data), IQueue (https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/data-structures/queue.html#queueing-with-persistent-datastore).

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Hazelcast is memory centric storage with respective trade-offs. Persistence options are designed to populate the cache faster upon start-up and to recovery faster after a failure. See the [Hot Restart](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/storage/hot-restart-persistence.html).

Use Hazelcast as a database for data you can recover or ignore if lost. Hz gives you many tools to recover the data: [MapStore](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/data-structures/map.html#loading-and-storing-persistent-data), [Connectors](https://jet-start.sh/docs/api/sources-sinks). I wouldn’t recommend using it when you need strong durability (as in “ACID” database), e.g. for a long-term storage.

Disclaimer: I work at Hazelcast